# fail to read message on the client end using C

Tags: java, c, sockets, protocol-buffers

I use protocol buffers to make data structure and on the server end I write the following code to send a message using Java while I receive the message on the client end using C.

Java Server:

```
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
GameResponse.Builder builder=GameResponse.newBuilder();
builder.build().writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

C Client:

```
while ((n = ::recv(sockfd, buf, BUFFLEN, 0)) > 0) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
    len += n;
}
```

Turns out the message sending from server was correct but it could not be received on the client. Looks like the while loop never break it went into a dead loop. We supposed it might be the reason that the C recv function never got a EOF to end the data transferring...

Comment: try to `writeDelimitedTo(os)` and why you are not using protobuf API at client side?

Comment: Are you sure, that `os.close()` actually closes the socket? The recv function will return 0 only when the connection is broken, otherwise it will just hang waiting for data.

Comment: I'm not responsible for the client end receiving....they'd like to use raw C code to work with socket...

Answer (score 1):

`recv()` returns `0` if the connection had been closed.

To close the connection from the client side, close the socket by calling `socket.close()`.

Comment: actually,the client socket was closed after receiving the data from server... and I also write socket.close() on the server end... plus,here comes another question of receiving data from client on the server end. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354591/receiving-data-from-client-on-the-server-end-failed) . I appreciate if u could help me!

Comment: @RyanZhu: I just recoginzed I mixed up server and client in my answer. Sry!

Comment: not at all..in fact,I really found out that once I close the socket at the client,I could get data correctly...but the client is not allowed to close cuz it still has the responsibility to receive data from server... so... I have to look for another way to solve this problem...