# Receiving data from client on the server end failed

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have asked several questions about protocol buffers about socket transferring...again,I got a problem when I want to receive data at the server end from the client.

here is the client end code:

```
int sendSystem(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes, int flags) {
return ::send(sockfd, buf, nbytes, flags);
```

}

it's like the client do send data by integers standing for each byte.so the data was transferring in bytes.

here is the server end code:

```
GameRequest gameRequest=GameRequest.parseFrom(CodedInputStream.newInstance(socket.getInputStream()));
GameRequest gameRequest=GameRequest.parseDelimitedFrom(socket.getInputStream());
GameRequest gameRequest=GameRequest.parseFrom(socket.getInputStream());
```

I have tried each ways above to receive data and parse it...turns out none is a good way..mostly I just got a message as "the message has an invalid tag" or if I turn on the debug mode,it just stand by at the line of the code above and I can't move to next step or move into the calling method cuz the button step over and step into was disabled...

Comment: I re-tagged this as "c++", since it's clearly not C.

Comment: protobuf streams do not know their own length; if you are keeping the stream open (i.e. if you don't close the outbound socket after send), then the receiver *will not know that the data is finished*. Unless you add "framing", such as a header with the number of bytes to read (and obviously process that at the receiver etc). This might explain some of the oddities..